# Return records in java

Tags: java

I need to return multiple records in to a variable, in below mention code with in while loop I am getting all the records but while return result I am getting only one record I don't know how to do

```
public String feed()
    {
        String projectname=null;
        String claintid=null;
        String projectstatus=null;
        String prjstartdate=null;
        String prjenddate=null;
        String lastmodified=null;
        String prjpinurl=null;
        String patientDetails=null;

        try 
        {
                Connection conn = getMySqlConnection();
                String simpleProc = "{ call Sp_RetPrjvals () }";
                CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(simpleProc);
                ResultSet rs=(ResultSet) cs.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
                   projectid=rs.getString(1);
                   projectname=rs.getString(2);
                   claintid=rs.getString(3);
                   projectstatus=rs.getString(4);
                   prjstartdate=rs.getString(5);
                   prjenddate=rs.getString(6);
                   lastmodified=rs.getString(7);
                   prjpinurl=rs.getString(8);

                   patientDetails=projectid+"|"+projectname+"|"+claintid+"|"+projectstatus+"|"+prjstartdate+"|"+prjenddate+"|"+lastmodified+"|"+prjpinurl;
                   //here i am getting two values before:::2|Sample project 2|1|WIP|2015-08-01 00:00:00.0|2016-08-01 00:00:00.0|2015-08-24 16:40:10.0|http://hcup-us.ahrq.gov/toolssoftware/ccs/ccs.jsp
before:::1|Sample project 1|1|WIP|null|null|2015-08-24 16:38:39.0|http://hcup-us.ahrq.gov/toolssoftware/ccs/ccs.jsp
                       }

                 conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        return patientDetails;
       // here i am getting only After:::1|Sample project 1|1|WIP|null|null|2015-08-24 16:38:39.0|http://hcup-us.ahrq.gov/toolssoftware/ccs/ccs.jsp

    }
```

Comment: Did you execute stored procedure on database and see ?

Comment: ya i have executed  i am getting two records and also in while loop i am getting those two record but while return i am getting one record

Comment: because you're doing this `patientDetails=projectid[etc]`, so on every loop you're resetting the string rather than concatenating to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
patientDetails is a `String` Object.
```

If you expet to be able to retun a *list* of striong, then you should use an array of *String* objects in that case.

Something like:

```
String[] patientDetails
```

Then in your code you should add each returned record to your array

Something like:

```
        patientDetails[i] = projectid+"|"+projectname+"|"+claintid+"|"+projectstatus+"|"+prjstartdate+"|"+prjenddate+"|"+lastmodified+"|"+prjpinurl;
i ++; //Initialize this *i* variable outside the while
```

Also change the signature of your method as:

```
public String[] feed()
```

Comment: String[] patientDetails i have done that code but i am getting  type mismatch error

Comment: Did you also change the way you set that array, as showed in my answer?

Comment: Update your answer, with what you have tried and what error you got.

Comment: patientDetails[i] =projectid+"|"+projectname+"|"+claintid+"|"+projectstatus+"|"+prjstartdate+"|"+prjenddate+"|"+lastmodified+"|"+prjpinurl;
          System.out.println("before:::"+patientDetails);
          i++;

Comment: return patientDetails; in this line i am getting type mis match cant not convert string[] to string error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you override your String. You have to add it to a list or an array.

For example: `List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>()`

and then you have to add the String you build on every while step into this array and retrun this array:

```
al.add(patientDetails);
```

your return statement follows this: `return al;`

your function header is then:

```
public List<String> feed(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't know your result size, you need a dynamic structure, like a list:

```
List<String> pacients = new ArrayList<>();

while(results.next()){

  ...
  String patientDetails = ....;
  pacients.add(patientDetails);
}
```

After this code you will have  alist of pacient details. But I would advise you to keep their data in an object, not a String;

```
class PatientDetails {
        String projectname; // you don't have to initialize with null, it's done by default
        String claintid;
        String projectstatus;
        String prjstartdate;
        String prjenddate;
        String lastmodified;
        String prjpinurl;
        String patientDetails;

       // getters & setters

       @Override
       public String toString(){
          return projectid+"|"+projectname+"|"+claintid+"|"+ ...;
       }
}
```

Now when you will want to print a PatientDetails you will get same result as your string representation.

And you would return a `List<PatientDetails>` holding your query results.